# Bunch of errors when I updated swift version

Tags: ios, swift

I updated an iOS application (not developed by myself) because as many of all you know if you want to upload a new build or a new application it should be now with the new SDK 13.

I haven't much experience with Swift and iOS but know I need to update this app previously running on swift 3 without problems, but when I converted it on Xcode 10.1 to swift 4 there were also a lot of new errors for me, I already found similar topics here about these type of errors, but since there isn't any documentation of the app and also I'm a newby on swift I not sure how to solve them. So at least I hope someone can help me to understand why there are this new errors just by updating the swift version.

The most recurrent errors I have are like this example, the following function was working, but with the update I have the following errors:

```
  func showDeleteView()
    {
        let view: EliminarDialogView = try! SwiftMessages.viewFromNib()
        view.configureDropShadow()
        view.eliminarAction = { _ in self.handleDeleteToken() ; SwiftMessages.hide() }
        view.cancelAction = { SwiftMessages.hide() }
        var config = SwiftMessages.defaultConfig
        config.interactiveHide = true
        config.presentationContext = .window(windowLevel: UIWindowLevelStatusBar)
        config.duration = .forever
        config.presentationStyle = .bottom
        config.dimMode = .gray(interactive: true)
        SwiftMessages.show(config: config, view: view)
```

`Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate`
&
`Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'window'`

Also if I select to fix it by the IDE there's another error:

`Value of type 'SwiftMessages.Config' has no member 'presentationContext'`

What I found here and surfing on the Internet was about this need to receive the same kind of variable on the list but since there's also the use of "_" I'm not sure how to handle this here.

EDITED

The update of the pod helped! but about which line of code is having the errors:

`Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate`

`Cannot convert value of type '(_) -> ()' to expected argument type '(() -> Void)?'`

`Value of type 'ActivarViewController' has no member 'startAnimating'`

On the following lines:

`view.eliminarAction = { _ in self.handleDeleteToken() ; SwiftMessages.hide() }`

`self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: { _ in }) }`

```
        `self.startAnimating(nil, message: "Procesando código de activación", messageFont: nil, type: NVActivityIndicatorType.ballScaleMultiple)`
```

Comment: At which line are you getting this error? Also, could you please post the types of `eliminarAction` and `cancelAction` closures?

Comment: I edited the post with the error line (sorry about that) and also I'm not sure about the types of that closures but I'll try to found them!

Comment: OK, to find the closure type just Alt+click on `eliminarAction` property.

Comment: @gcharita  '  var eliminarAction: (() -> Void)?
    var cancelAction: (() -> Void)?
    
    atIBAction func alCancelar(_ sender: Any) {
        cancelAction?()
    }
    atIBAction func alEliminar(_ sender: Any) {
        eliminarAction?()
    }'Alt+click does not return any documentation, but this is what I got with Command click

Comment: Try replacing this line `view.eliminarAction = { _ in self.handleDeleteToken() ; SwiftMessages.hide() }` with this one `view.eliminarAction = { self.handleDeleteToken() ; SwiftMessages.hide() }`. It's the same but without `_ in`.

Comment: @gcharita `Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate` Did it but the error stills

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try to update `SwiftMessages` as follows:

```
pod 'SwiftMessages', '~> 5.0'
```

Comment: I downgraded it from version 8.0 but there still some errors `Installing SwiftMessages 5.0.1 (was 8.0.2 and source changed to `https://cdn.cocoapods.org/` from `trunk`)`

Comment: Can you write down those errors so I can figure it out

Comment: I edited the post with them, also noticed the most of the errores are also from one Framework called UIKit

Answer (score 0):

`Cannot convert value of type '(_) -> ()' to expected argument type '(() -> Void)?'` - If there is no arguments then don't use Void in at all.

`Value of type 'ActivarViewController' has no member 'startAnimating'` - `startAnimating` starts the animation of the progress indicator, so it can be called via `UIActivityIndicator`.